# Playing some videos at the same time in recyclerview causes heavy process in main thread

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi this is what i want to do :
I need a recyclerveiw that should play some videos at the same time , about 3 or 4 video at the same time ; i search lot and finally found 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4' good for my work , and yeah that works well , But i have serious problem after doing my job and its that i have lag while loading recyclerview it take about 4-5 second to load it even when it should load only 7-8 item , and even after loading the scroll is to slow , i read my log and its the problem :
Choreographer: Skipped 121 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread
plz help me to fix my problem and my slow recyclerview

```
public class LunchDinnerMenuTypeFragmentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LunchDinnerMenuTypeFragmentAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ManuTypeFragmentBeanclass> countries;
    private List<SecondLevelMenu> secondLevelMenus;
    @RawRes
    private int mVideoResId;
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context mContext;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private Thread thread;

    public LunchDinnerMenuTypeFragmentAdapter(ArrayList<ManuTypeFragmentBeanclass> countries, int rowLayout, Context context,List<SecondLevelMenu>secondLevelMenus) {

        this.countries = countries;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.secondLevelMenus=secondLevelMenus;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return countries == null ? 0 : countries.size();
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        ManuTypeFragmentBeanclass myItem = countries.get(i);
        mVideoResId = myItem.backimage;
        //ScalableType scalableType = ScalableType.values()[i];
        ScalableType scalableType = ScalableType.CENTER_CROP;
        //viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        viewHolder.setScalableType(scalableType);
        viewHolder.name.setText(myItem.getName());
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(final ViewHolder holder) {

        //holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        setVideo(holder.mVideoView, holder.getAdapterPosition());
        holder.mVideoView.setScalableType(holder.mScalableType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
        try {
            holder.mVideoView.setRawData(mVideoResId);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        holder.mVideoView.seekTo(10);
    }

    private void setVideo(final ScalableVideoView videoView, int position) {
        try {
//            if (position == 0) {
//                mVideoResId = R.raw.hamburger;
//            }
         /*   if (position == 3) {
                mVideoResId = R.raw.pepsi_fries_salad;
            }*/
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    mVideoResId = R.raw.hamburger1;
                    break;
                case 1 :
                    mVideoResId = R.raw.drinks;
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    mVideoResId = R.raw.salad;
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    mVideoResId = R.raw.sandwich;
                    break;
                case 4 :
                    mVideoResId = R.raw.pizza;
                    break;
                case 5 :
                    mVideoResId = R.raw.kentucky;
                    break;
                case 6 :
                    mVideoResId = R.raw.kalzone;
                    break;
            }
            videoView.setRawData(mVideoResId);
            videoView.setVolume(0, 0);
            videoView.setLooping(true);
            videoView.prepare(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    videoView.start();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            //ignore
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView name, description, number, timer;
        public ScalableVideoView profileimage, mVideoView;
        ScalableType mScalableType;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //profileimage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            mVideoView = (ScalableVideoView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.second_backimage);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.second_name);

            // backimage.setMediaController(mediaController);

            //description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            //number = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            //timer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timer);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (onItemClickListener != null) {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClick(itemView, getLayoutPosition(), new ViewHolder(v),secondLevelMenus);
            }
        }

        public void setScalableType(ScalableType type) {
            mScalableType = type;
        }

    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position, ViewHolder viewHolder,List<SecondLevelMenu> secondLevelMenus);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }


    public void setVideoForView(final ViewHolder holder) {
        ((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setVideo(holder.mVideoView, holder.getAdapterPosition());
                holder.mVideoView.setScalableType(holder.mScalableType);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Please attach some details/code about your implementation.

Comment: @lifeisfoo i attached my adapter

Comment: Your app will obviously lag if you are trying to play 3 or 4 videos at once. It may not lag if you use videos of smaller resolution.

Comment: @NabinBhandari All size and all res is tested the current videos are 480dp and about 1mg